# How can I prevent the user from going backwards using getX in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to prevent the user from going back to the login screen using getX

```
onPressed: () {
                  Get.to(() => HomeScreen());
                },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To navigate to the next screen and don’t want to go back to the previous screen (for use in SplashScreens, login screens and etc.) we can use it like this,

```
Get.off(NewScreen())
```

To navigate to the next screen and cancel all previous routes (useful in shopping carts apps , polls, and tests) we can use it like this,

```
Get.offAll(NewScreen())
```

For more see this by @hetashree : https://medium.com/mindful-engineering/lets-getx-in-flutter-4eaff2826ac7